# Sketching a Cyclic Quadrilateral

Tags: geometry

In cyclic quadrilateral $ABCD$ consider $DD_1 ⊥ DC$ with $D_1$ on line $AB$, $BB_1 ⊥ AB$ with $B_1$ on line $DC$.
Prove that $AC ∥ B_1D_1$.

---

I'm having trouble drawing this cyclic quadrilateral. At first, I put $D_1$ at the intersection of $AB$ and $DA$ and $B_1$ at the intersection of $DC$ and $BC$. But such placements for $D_1$ and $B_1$ made $AC$ the exact same line as $B_1D_1$. So that didn't work. Now I guessing and testing to no avail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea is that the intersections don't have to occur inside the circle. The question has $D_1$ on line $AB$ and $B_1$ on line $DC$. Here's a picture that can hopefully sort things out.

[image: circle woo]

Comment: It seems I neglected the fact that D1 and B1 are not part of the cyclical quadrilateral. Thank you.